# storyboard:This class is not key value coding-compliant for the key

Tags: storyboard

I use a storyboard layouts.The process is like this：

A[UIViewController] ----Modal--->[UINavigationController]-----root view controller----->B[UIViewController]

And now I need a value from A to B；So I wrote the following code in A：

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

    [segue.destinationViewController setValue:@"test" forKey:@"type"];

}
```

But at the time of execution, appear [*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key type.']

Can be seen that value is arrived the UINavigationController.
How to pass parameters UINavigationController root view[b]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    UINavigationController * nav = segue.destinationViewController;
    [[nav.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] setValue:@"test" forKey:@"type"];
}
```